# Remote assist into a PC that is remote assisting another PC?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-assistance

I'm trying to Microsoft Remote Assist a PC for monitoring/demonstration purposes while that PC remotes into other PCs (to assist other users). Is it possible to do this in a Windows 10 Pro environment?

Thanks much.

Comment: You cannot spin up two instances of the same MS Remote Assist per the MSRA.exe file. You have to have one of those sessions using the MSRA tool and then the other tool using another non-MSRA solution such as MS Teams desktop sharing, Team Viewer, etc. If ComputerA is helping ComputerB using MSRA.exe and you want to use MSRA.exe to access Computer A from ComputerC, this will NOT work. Use MS Teams, TeamViewer, or another tool that's not MSRA to connect from ComputerC to ComputerA to see that remote MSRA session.

Comment: I've never tried mixing MS Quick Assist with MS Remote Assistance but those may be two Windows 10 native solutions that may work well together.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done (I have done this). A uses the MS App to get to B.  B uses a different instances of MS App on B to get to  C.  There are other remote assistance tools if you need them.

It is enabled at the Client PC (not from the PC trying to access).

It is only enabled by the Client for security reasons.

Control Panel, System, Windows Settings page, scroll down right side to Advanced System Settings.

Click on the Remote Tab and in the Remote Desktop settings (lower half) enable Allow Remote connections to this computer.

Restart after that and a source computer will be able to access with Windows RDP knowing the name or IP address of the client computer.

I have done when I have need to.

[image: Allow Remote Access]